# parsing JSON using javascript gives me undefined while getting the value from the json response

Tags: javascript, json

i am parsing an json string usin javascript

```
    {
      "head":   {
        "example": "0"
         },
      "res":   {
        "@test": "121",
        "@found": "5"
     }
}
```

i am getting the http response from the remote site and i am using javascript to extract the @found value .i used the below code .

```
 var json=eval('('+request.responseText+')');
        alert(json.head.res.@found);
```

gives me a null value can u please tell me how can i parse this.

Comment: res is parallel to head. Iterate till what depth it returns object. Try alert(json.res.@found);

Answer (score 3):

```
alert(json.head.res['@found']);
```

@ is not valid to start a variable name, so you have to use bracket notation. Or change the variable name to be valid.

> Basically, in regular expression form: [a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*. In
>   other words, the first character can be a letter or _ or $, and the
>   other characters can be letters or _ or $ or numbers.

[What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names/1661249#1661249)

---

Per Topera's answer head and res are on the same level in your object not nested.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute "res" is not inside "head" attribute.

Try this: `json.res['@found']`

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(json.res['@found']);
```

`res` is not inside head.

Answer (score 0):

Try `json.res['@found']`. JavaScript object properties that are not valid variable names cannot be accessed using dot notation. Also, as noted by others, @found is not in head.

Answer (score 0):

fix these 3 things :

- `@` is not a valid variable name character. you should consider the `[]` syntax instead of the "dot" one.
- `res` is not in `head`.
- please don't use `eval`. I strongly advise you to use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`

```
var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
alert(json.res['@found']);
```

Comment: thanks for your advice and the json is converted from xml so it has the name starts with @ .i used json-lib to convert it in java .